# Import "pygame" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports) error in VSCode on mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, module, pygame

```
import pygame

#initialise
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit:
            running = False
```

This code actually runs, but the error does not go away. I am following a pygame tutorial that uses pycharm. Is the issue the program I am using?

I'm a beginner and can't figure this out at all.

Comment: The problem is probably a mismatch of used python version/environment between what get's execute and what the IDE analyses. Try typing `python --version` and checking wheter that matches with what is configured in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the global environment, you need to reopen the VSCode after you install the package you want to import.

[image]

If you are using the virtual environment, `Plycance Language Server` can detect the packages automatically after you installed them.

[image]

Comment: @eklavyaisabird I submit a bug in Github: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1474

Answer (score 3):

After a long time trying to solve the problem, I had to manually add the library folder in Pylance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh9tP.png)

It may be that the location of your libraries is in a different place, but after the Python folder the location doesn't change (unless you changed it yourself), in my case it still didn't work, if yours doesn't work either, put: C:\python\python310\lib\site-packages\pygame
If you installed without making any changes your python folder is in c:\Users\Your user\AppData\Roaming\Python...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem on VSCode even though the package was already there using [pip install pygame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p852m.png) and I had to add the library folder in Pylance manually, I copied the library path and pasted it to Pylance extra path setting. It solved my problem. [Pylance extra path setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5dSN.png)

Answer (score 1):

@eklavyaisabird - I have faced same issue on VSCode but I had added `./sources` on Pylance extra path setting, it fixed the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After adding it to the environment using pycharm, it somehow fixed the issue in VSCode as well. Weird. I wonder how I would do the same thing with only vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the python interpreter you are using contains the pygame libraries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to check if the editor's current Python version matches the correct directory path of the Python imported version. In order to do so,

- First, we need to check the Python version shown on the bottom panel of the editor and click on it.
- After clicking, we will get the above popup showing all the Python versions currently installed in the local system.
  [Step 1 (Matching Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsR8s.png)
- Click the correct directory path (matching the one in which Pygame is currently installed)
- You may also edit the default import path from the Python settings.json file (search "Python" inside VS Code "Settings") and add the correct directory path in the "python.defaultInterpreterPath" field.

[Step 2 (Editing Settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4srAV.png)

[Step 3 (Adding Correct Directory Path to settings.json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFgY0.png)

This solution worked for me!